# Error copying SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to upgrade a database from a SQL Server 2000 instance to a SQL Server 2008 instance.  I'm doing this by right clicking on the database and selecting copy database. My current issue is that I'm getting this error in the log file:

> OnError,AQUE-SQLDEV,NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,aque-db2000_aque-sqldev_sql2008_Transfer Objects
>   Task,{F0ACDE4D-D023-400C-BE3C-91CD3A537988},{40E67169-0F3F-4F86-AD2E-6E2CB532BA5C},18/10/2011
>   15:38:37,18/10/2011 15:38:37,0,0x,Script failed for User 'WebUser'. 
>   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(DependencyCollection
>   depList, SqlSmoObject[] objects)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(SqlSmoObject[]
>   objects)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ITransferMetadataProvider.SaveMetadata()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dts.DtsTransferProvider.Configure(ITransferMetadataProvider
>   metadataProvider)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.GetTransferProvider()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferDatabasesUsingSMOTransfer()
>   InnerException-->Creating a user without an associated login is not
>   supported in SQL Server 2008.;

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: "Does anyone know why this might be happening?" ->>> 'Creating a user without an associated login is not supported in SQL Server 2008'

Comment: I did know that but how do I prevent the wizard from creating such users?

Comment: Don't use `Copy database` - create a backup on SQL Server 2000 and restore on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error it sounds like you need to create a login first on the SQL 2008 server that matches the same login/user that exists on the SQL 2000 server.  You could do a couple of things:

1. create a new database in 2008 to migrate to
2. create a new login in 2008 that matches the existing login from sql 2000
3. map the new login to that new database from step #1
4. run the copy database wizard

If it was me, I would do as marc_s suggested and perform a full backup of the existing database on sql 2000, then restore to a blank database in sql 2008.  If you can, update the compatibility mode in database properties to be 2008.  I've done this hundreds of times and works like a charm.

Comment: In my case it was an "orphan login". The source database had a SQL login listed under Databases/<dbname>/security/users but there was no corresponding login in Databases/security/logins -- I deleted the orphan and the wizard was happy.

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be that a file with the new Database name already exist on the filesystem. We encountered this when we renamed Database X to X_Old, and tried to copy database Y to X. This cannot be done, because database X_Old is still associated with the filename X.

Either delete the conflicting database, or rename the file on the file system.

See http://codecopy.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/error-while-copying-a-database/